# How to find specific strings in dataframe using for loop?

Tags: r

I'm using for loop to find all specific strings (df2$x2) in another dataframe (df1$x1) and what my purpose is create new column the df1$test and write the df$x2 value.

For example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x1 = c("TE-T6-3 XYZ12X","TE-D31L-2 QWE12X","TE-H6-1 ABC12X","TE-D31L-2 QWE12X","EC20 QWX12X"),
                  Y = c(2017,2017,2018,2018,2017),
                  Sales = c(25,50,30,40,90))
df1$x1 <- as.character(as.factor(df1$x1))

df2 <- data.frame(x2 = c("TE-T6-5","TE-D31L-2","TE-H6-15","EC500","EC20","TE-D31L-2"),
                  Y = c(2018,2017,2018,2017,2018,2018),
                  P = c(100,300,200,50,150,300))
df2$x2 <- as.character(as.factor(df2$x2))

for(i in 1:nrow(df2)){

  f <- df2[i,1]

  df1$test <- ifelse(grepl(f, df1$x1),f,"not found")

}
```

What should I do after the end of loop? I know that problem is y is refreshing every time. I tried "if" statement to create new data frame and save outputs but it didn't work. It's writing only one specific string.

Thank you in advance.

Expected output:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x1 = c("TE-T6-3 XYZ12X","TE-D31L-2 QWE12X","TE-H6-1 ABC12X","TE-D31L-2 QWE12X","EC20 QWX12X"),
             output = c("not found","TE-D31L-2","not found","TE-D31L-2","EC20"))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you rephrase your question by showing us clear input and expected output?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I edited. Is it clear?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to have one new column for each string? if that is what you need, your code should be:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x1 = c("TE-T6-3 XYZ12X","TE-D31L-2 QWE12X","TE-H6-1 ABC12X","TE-D31L-2 QWE12X","EC20 QWX12X"),
                  Y = c(2017,2017,2018,2018,2017),
                  Sales = c(25,50,30,40,90))
df1$x1 <- as.character(as.factor(df1$x1))

df2 <- data.frame(x2 = c("TE-T6-5","TE-D31L-2","TE-H6-15","EC500","EC20","TE-D31L-2"),
                  Y = c(2018,2017,2018,2017,2018,2018),
                  P = c(100,300,200,50,150,300))
df2$x2 <- as.character(as.factor(df2$x2))

for(i in 1:nrow(df2)){

  f <- df2[i,1]
  df1$test <- ""
  df1$test<-ifelse(grepl(f, df1$x1),T,F)
  colnames(df1) <- c(colnames(df1[1:length(df1[1,])-1]),f)

}
```

it creates a new column with a temp name and then rename it with the string evaluated. Also i change "not found" for F, but you can use whatever you want.

[EDIT:]
If you want that expected output, you can use this code:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x1 = c("TE-T6-3 XYZ12X","TE-D31L-2 QWE12X","TE-H6-1 ABC12X","TE-D31L-2 QWE12X","EC20 QWX12X"),
                  Y = c(2017,2017,2018,2018,2017),
                  Sales = c(25,50,30,40,90))
df1$x1 <- as.character(as.factor(df1$x1))

df2 <- data.frame(x2 = c("TE-T6-5","TE-D31L-2","TE-H6-15","EC500","EC20","TE-D31L-2"),
                  Y = c(2018,2017,2018,2017,2018,2018),
                  P = c(100,300,200,50,150,300))
df2$x2 <- as.character(as.factor(df2$x2))
df1$output <- "not found"

for(i in 1:nrow(df2)){
  f <- df2[i,1]
  df1$output[grepl(f, df1$x1)]<-f

}
```

Very similar of what you have done, but it was needed to index which rows you have to write. 
This only works when the data only can have one match, it is a little more complicated if you can have more than one match for row. But i think that's not your problem.

Comment: There are other more elegant solutions, i tried to change your strategy and code the less possible.

Comment: FYI, no need for `ifelse` in `grepl`. If it exists, it will produce `TRUE`, and if not, then `FALSE`

Comment: Thank you but I need is one new column as shown image or expected output above.

Comment: That's what i want! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to split the `df1$x1` strings on space and merge (or `match` since you are only interested in one variable)on `df2$x2`, i.e.

```
v1 <- sub('\\s+.*', '', df1$x1)
v1[match(v1, df2$x2)]
#[1] NA          "TE-D31L-2" NA          "TE-D31L-2" "EC20"
```

Comment: Thank you. I know it and used but the given example is easy. Actually, the strings have more than two blanks and sometimes their place is not stable. So, for loop method will be good way I think.

Comment: You need to include things like that in your question. Be explicit and explain your problem well, mentioning any corner cases. Otherwise, it's a waste of time for both of us!